# Shadow not appearing under UIImageView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, shadow

I have written the following code to download and display an image in the cells of a tableView. However, the drop shadow isn't appearing at all and I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
cell.societyImage.setIndicatorStyle(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
cell.societyImage.setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
cell.societyImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: pictureURLs[objectIds[indexPath.row]]!),completed: { (image, error, cache, url) in                
     cell.societyImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.7).CGColor
     cell.societyImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3)
     cell.societyImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
     cell.societyImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
})
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Add shadowradius and clipsToBound properties to your code, will resolved your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About `maskToBounds`: if you put it true then you won't see shadow as it clips sublayer where else in false it allow to extent layer.

```
...    
cell.societyImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: pictureURLs[objectIds[indexPath.row]]!),completed: { (image, error, cache, url) in     
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.societyImage.bounds).CGPath
         cell.societyImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.7).CGColor
         cell.societyImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3)
         cell.societyImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
         cell.societyImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
         cell.societyImage.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
         cell.societyImage.layer.radius = 2
    })   
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line

```
cell.societyImage.layer.masksToBounds = false

cell.societyImage.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set following parameters,

```
 cell.societyImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
 cell.societyImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
 cell.societyImage.layer.shadowRadius = 4
 cell.societyImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
 cell.societyImage.layer.masksToBounds = false;
 cell.societyImage.clipsToBounds = false;
```